# Spring Boot application not deploying - Unable to create XADataSource instance

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, atomikos

I'm trying to deploy a simple Spring Boot application. `application.properties` contains the following:

```
spring.datasource.name=MyDS
spring.datasource.username=user
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.xa.data-source-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource
spring.datasource.password=passwd
spring.jpa.database=mysql
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect
spring.datasource.url=jdbc\:mysql\://host\:3306/mydb
hibernate.dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
entitymanager.packagesToScan: /
```

Upon deploying I get the following:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create XADataSource instance from 'com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource'
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.createXaDataSourceInstance(XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:107)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.createXaDataSource(XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:94)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.dataSource(XADataSourceAutoConfiguration.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162)
        ... 47 more
```

I've only encountered this kind of exception when the XA DataSource was set to `org.mysql.jdbc.MySQLDataSource`. In that case setting it to `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource` is supposed to do the trick. Any suggestions are welcome.

UPDATE: after bringing in the older versions of Atomikos in `pom.xml` I can choose between `atomikos-util 3.8.0` in which case the `spring-boot:run` fails with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atomikos.util.Assert`. If however I change the version to `atomikos-util 4.0.0` or higher I get `com.atomikos.diagnostics.Console`.

Answer (score 3):

```
spring.datasource.xa.properties.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

You also need to tell which driver xa datasource will use

Comment: I just did that, but I'm getting the very same exception

Answer (score 1):

```
@Bean
public DataSource dataSource() {
      DataSource dataSource = new DataSource();
      ....
      return dataSource;
}
```

This might do the trick

Comment: I created the following bean:
<code>
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().type(MysqlXADataSource.class).build();
    }
</code>

Now I get the following: `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.atomikos.icatch.HeuristicMessage` despite Atomikos `transactions-jta` being already there in the pom.xml.